# A Replace of special character '$' to '_' works well in SSMS, while it doesn't in sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, replace, special-characters, sqlcmd

I'm trying to execute a query in SQL Server 2019 (v15) and facing an issue. The replace works well in SSMS, while it doesn't when the same query is executed in sqlcmd

*Actual Query*

```sql
SELECT 
    RTRIM(DB_NAME(dbid)) AS dbName,
    COUNT(dbid) AS ActiveSessions,
    RTRIM(loginame) AS LoginName 
FROM 
    sys.sysprocesses 
WHERE 
    dbid > 0 
GROUP BY 
    dbid, loginame;
```

Result in SSMS:

```
master  1   NT SERVICE\TELEMETRY$MSSQLSERVER01
```

Result in sqlcmd:

```
master  1   NT SERVICE\TELEMETRY
```

To fix the '$' in the loginName, modified the query as below using `REPLACE`:

```sql
SELECT 
    RTRIM(DB_NAME(dbid)) AS dbName,
    COUNT(dbid) AS ActiveSessions,
    REPLACE(RTRIM(loginame), '$', '_') AS LoginName 
FROM 
    sys.sysprocesses 
WHERE 
    dbid > 0 
GROUP BY 
    dbid, loginame;
```

Results in SSMS:

```
master  1   NT SERVICE\TELEMETRY_MSSQLSERVER01
```

Results in `sqlcmd`:

```
master  1   NT SERVICE\TELEMETRY
```

**Issue**

Results are different for the same query.

I have these questions and would highly appreciate if answered:

- Why does the same query behave differently for the same language?
- Why does the query only work in SSMS and not in `sqlcmd`?
- What should the query be to work in `sqlcmd`?
- Why is the value (`MSSQLSERVER01`) after `$` getting truncated in `sqlcmd`?

Comment: Why does the username need "fixing"? Why are you using `sys.sysprocesses` it's old and for compatibility only? You should be using `sys.dm_exec_connections` and `sys.dm_exec_sessions` instead

Comment: perhaps the logins are exposed differently through different systems rather than replace is "buggy". what happens if you run the query without any replaces?

Comment: You need to show us what exactly are you doing in your command line. It looks like $ is a special character and you might not handle that properly. Also can you describe what you are "fixing" - the login name is not "broken"

Comment: sqlcmd uses the `$` character to introduce variables in T-SQL scripts, e.g.: `$(VariableNameHere)`, but a standalone `$` shouldn't affect things. What happens if you add [`-x`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd-utility#-x) (lowercase x) to the sqlcmd command line to disable variable substitution?

Comment: @Chalieface, We need the full username (NT SERVICE\TELEMETRY$MSSQLSERVER01 or NT SERVICE\TELEMETRY_MSSQLSERVER01) along with MSSQLSERVER01 in the application where this query is being executed. As MSSQLSERVER01 is being removed from the resultset, the application is running into issues

Comment: @siggemannen, We added replace to ensure MSSQLSERVER01 doesn't get removed in resultset. Other special characters appear in the resultset except $ and characters adjoining $. To fix it, we thought to replace $ with _. But still, it didn't work.

Comment: @vasek, Executed below query as it is
1> SELECT RTRIM(DB_NAME(dbid)) as dbName,COUNT(dbid) as ActiveSessions,RTRIM(loginame) as LoginName FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE dbid > 0 GROUP BY dbid, loginame;
2> GO

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I'll check this

Comment: I think it's a difference depending on how you are connecting. Sqlcmd is local while ssms perhaps connects though tcpip. You don't need the part after $ cause it's the computer name you are at. This is guesswork of course